# SQL Error Code 1055. Minimum date by Flag by Group

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by, min

I'm trying to find the minimum date at which patient took a drug with a certain flag.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
create table Schema.Want as select 
*, min(case when Flag="True" then Date end) as First_Date 
from Schema.Have group by Patient_ID;
```

I have also tried listing out all the variables, but that didn't help either.  When I run that code I get the Error Code 1055 associated with "only_full_group".  I've seen others suggesting that I turn this off (which I have NOT tried yet) but I'm concerned about why this error is being thrown in the first place.  When I get this error code, does that mean that I have duplicate rows in my table?

I've got Patient_ID(NUM), Drug_ID(NUM), Quantity(NUM), Fill_Date (Date/Char), Flag(CHAR), Comp_Set(CHAR), and Drug_strength(CHAR).  So if one patient filled two prescriptions for the same strength and quantity of the same exact drug on the same day, then two of their rows would be identical.  That doesn't seem likely to me though.

All I need to do is create a separate column with the oldest date at which a patient was prescribed a certain drug.  My code worked using proc sql in SAS, but not when I use MySQL.  Thanks for your help in advance!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remerge the MIN() value back onto the detail records.  If you check the log in SAS you will see that it says that it is doing the remerge for you.

```
create table Schema.Want as 
select a.*,b.First_Date
from Schema.Have a 
inner join 
(select Patient_ID, min(case when Flag="True" then Date end) as First_Date 
from Schema.Have group by Patient_ID) b
on a.Patient_ID=b.Patient_ID
;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use select into:

```
select 
*, min(case when Flag="True" then Date end) as First_Date  into Schema.Want
from Schema.Have group by Patient_ID
```

Also replace * with column names and group by all names

Comment: should be fine if you spell out each field

Comment: I tried spelling out each field in the select statement and I got the same error.  Correct me if I'm wrong, but if I include all names in the group by statement, I'll just get the Date for each entry?  Like it won't give me the lowest date by patient, but rather just the date of that row?


Also the select into did not work, I'm not sure which version of SQL I'm using but it doesn't seem to be supported.

Comment: it'll roll up to whatever level you group by to

Answer (score 0):

All the values you have in the `Select` except the  `min` must also be  in the `group by` clause.

```
create table Schema.Want as select 
Patient_ID, min(case when Flag="True" then Date end) as First_Date 
from Schema.Have group by Patient_ID;
```

Note: If you have other numeric variables in the `select`; you will have to give them an aggregate function (min, max, avg ..) and not include them in the `group by` .

I recommend doing a select only in SQL before deciding to create the table:

```
select Patient_ID, min(case when Flag="True" then Date end) as First_Date 
from Schema.Have group by Patient_ID;
```

Comment: If I add all the variables to the `group by` wont that make each line unique and then prevent the grouping from being done at the patient level?

Comment: That's right but you may get other error as well. You should always group by categorical variables.

Comment: Add in the question an example of the data you have  and what you want (including their data type) and I will add to my answer a working SQL code for it.